# Geting APK file to work

Tags: android, adb

I know to install apk file on emulator you type,

```
adb install [apk file name]
```

So, I followed and I have received this error,

```
antz@antz-90X3A:~/Android/androidmalware$ adb install 01_AngryBirdsRiov110.apk   
error: device not found  
- waiting for device -
```

when i checked android android virtual device, I have an device.

Do I have to something else to link?

Comment: Try 'adb devices' what does it return? And is the emulator already running?

Comment: Well that Directory don't sound very user friendly.

Comment: i get nothing for list of devices when i type adb devices. whats the command for runnin the emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command for running emulator is:

```
emulator -avd <youravd.avd>
```

Sounds like you don't have an emulator or device connected to your computer.  You can check if you have a device available by typing:

```
adb devices
```

Just because you created an AVD doesn't mean it is running.  You need to start an emulator using the AVD you created.